# Calculate exit code with $? in shell

Tags: linux, shell

Could you guys help to give the algorithm used to generate $? in shell from exit code in program? For example,

```
  $? is 1 for exit(1);
  $? is 255 for exit(-1);
```

So I can infer exit code from $?

```
  $? is 1 => exit code is 1
  $? is 255 => exit code is -1
```

For something special,

```
  $? is 0 for exit(256);
  $? is 1 for exit(257);
```

Could anyone give the algorithm in shell used to generate $? with exit code, so that I can **know the exit code only by observing $?** after executing a command.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: To answer the question below, I added this example.

```
----a.c----
1 #include <stdlib.h>
2 int main()
3 {
4   exit(-1);
5 }
ning@m:~/work/02_test/ctest> gcc a.c
ning@m:~/work/02_test/ctest> ./a.out 
ning@m:~/work/02_test/ctest> echo $?
255
ning@m:~/work/02_test/ctest>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; Updated explaining -1 and 256. No algorithm, just an 8 bit return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash, $? is the exit code of the last command. Running a shell script .

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 113
```

then `echo $?` shows 113. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html for more info

With BASH there are some [common exit codes](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html).

The return value is just an 8bit Int. Exit codes 255 means out of range, so -1. The reason you are seeing 256->0 and 257->1 is it's wrapping around. Basically the exit value modulo 256.

All of this is true with Bash or C